# Automatic backup of Jenkins data when EC2 is terminating

Tags: amazon-ec2

A brief background - I have my Jenkins installed in EC2 (Linux2) with EFS backend - and everything is rolled out using terraform and shell scripts. I am trying to derive a 2 part solution to backup and restore Jenkins data

- in the first part, I need to backup my Jenkins data in an S3 bucket
  when I terminate the EC2 instance
- in the 2nd part, get the data back
  from that S3 when I deploy the infra.

Few facts,

- /var/lib/jenkins is
  mounted to an EFS I do not destroy that EFS even if the rest of the
  infa is destroyed.
- I do not have ELB or auto-scaling as I do not need
  it is for home lab
- I do not want to
  keep Jenkins EC2 running when I am not using it and destroy the infra
  but just keep the data when I need to fire up a new Jenkins.

I am able to do the 2nd part and able to retrieve data back into Jenkins. However, I am stuck in the first part. Below shell script "backup_backend.sh" works perfectly when I run it manually from within EC2.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop jenkins
sudo tar -czvf jenkins-backup.tar.gz /var/lib/jenkins
aws s3 cp jenkins-backup.tar.gz s3://XXX-jenkins-backup/jenkins-backup.tar.gz
```

Now I created a service script which will trigger when EC2 is terminated and for that I have a service script as below residing in /etc folder in EC2.:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shutdown Service
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
Requires=network-online.target network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/etc/backup_backend.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=900

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now there is another script that installs Jenkins and other related packages on EC2 and I kept it within null_resouce block in my terraform code. As part of that script, I run the below commands to add the above service:

```
sudo cp /tmp/shutdown.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/shutdown.service
sudo systemctl enable shutdown.service
sudo systemctl start shutdown.service
```

My problem is this service indeed gets triggered when I reboot or terminate EC2, but the zip file size is a lot lesser than when I run "backup_backend.sh" script manually. I am guessing it's a problem with the service script. Is it a timeout issue or anything else? Can anybody suggest what should be the solution?

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. Why not just take a snapshot of the EFS volume after terminating the instance?

Comment: Thanks, I added a cron job in EC2 to periodically take snapshots of EFS.